# In the case of a server application, is detatching threads considered good, neutral, or poor design

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

I recently wrote a simple tcp server using winsock using an online guide. I then tried to multithread it without the help of a guide. After a little struggle I ended up succeeding, but only by detaching the threads.

I have an infinite loop that whenever `accept()` returns a `SOCKET`, it creates a `Handler`, and calls `handle()` with the `SOCKET` result of `accept()` passed to it.
This is the `handle()` function which takes the socket from the `accept()` call and creates the thread which calls `processData`:

```
void Handler::handle(SOCKET socket)
{
    std::thread handlerThread([socket]{
        processData(socket);
    });
}
```

Here is the actual `processData` function, which is a static function in `Handler`:

```
void Handler::processData(SOCKET socket)
{
    try
    {
        const int buffLength = 512;
        char recvBuff[buffLength];
        int recvResult = recv(socket, recvBuff, buffLength, 0);

        if(recvResult > 0)
        {
            std::cout << recvBuff << std::endl;
        }

        closesocket(socket);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code would `abort()` on the `recv()` call with the code R6010 somehow escaping the try-catch. It wasn't until I changed the `handle` function to this:

```
void Handler::handle(SOCKET socket)
{
    std::thread handlerThread([socket]{
        processData(socket);
    });

    handlerThread.detach();
}
```

that it was able to get past the `recv()` call.

If anyone could explain **why detaching the thread had an effect on recv()** and knows **if there is a more desired design pattern where you do not have to detach the worker threads**, I would be very thankful if you would share it with me.

If that is too specific, maybe give your opinion on **when it is ok to detach a thread**.

Comment: You sure it's the recv() call that blows and not the cout stream?  When you detach the threads, what is output?  What happens if you call cout.write(recvBuff,recvResult)?

Comment: I debugged it and it didn't get past the recv call. When I detatch, I get the output I expect that was sent from a local TCP client application. I think @mkaes was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

From the Spec:

> 30.3.1.3 thread destructor [thread.thread.destr] ~thread();
>   If joinable(), calls std::terminate(). Otherwise, has no effects.

In your first case the destructor is called when the `handle` returns as your thread object is on the stack. Since your underlaying thread is still running and blocked in the `recv` function `std::terminate()` gets called. Which eventually lead to the `abort()` call.
When you detach the thread you can destroy the `std::thread` object because it is no longer joinable.

I personally try to avoid detached threads. So I would prefer in your case either a thread pool or you keep track of your thread objects by storing them e.g in a vector.

Comment: Why doesn't it terminate at an earlier point in time, like the line `const int buffLength = 512;`? Does the `handlerThread` just execute so fast that it gets to the blocking `recv` call, and then the `handle` function catches up and returns, thereby destructing `handlerThread`?

Comment: It is always hard to reason about multi threaded issues. In theory it can terminate at any place. I think on windows your thread will keep executing as long as you see the abort window. At least with asserts there was some kind of strange behavior and maybe with abort too.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by @mkaes, as long as the thread is not detached, it works in the context of the thread object, so it is stopped when the object is destroyed.

As far as threads are concerned, I either work with temporary threads or with static threads.  Typically, on servers, static threads should not be stopped, so they can be detached.  For temporary threads, you either want some result, so you have to join them at some point or you don't, so they can be detached.

The problem with threads in general is gracefully ending your application.  This is even harder if you have detached threads, because even if you signal them to stop, you need an extra mechanism to find out whether all threads have ended (and even then you're never 100% sure), so that seems the main reason to avoid detached threads.